# Execute migrations with Doctrine and Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Something I don't understand : when i run migrations with doctrine: migrations: migrate command, it only runs one migration, although there are several to run. I have to re-order the command several times. And sometimes it blocks. In the documentation it is clearly specified that the migrations are executed up to the most recent version.

[image]

In the Doctrine docs I can read :
[image]

So what's wrong ? :)

Comment: Does it returns you any error when blocking ? Does it block on the same file ?

Comment: In fact the blockage was due to unnecessary migration. But I have to run the command 10 times if I have 10 migrations files.